# How can i give my image an initial position before it starts moving with the mouse?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm working on this pygame game and i'm just getting started but got a bit confused because i want the image to move in the x-axis along with the mouse but when i run the program i want the image to show up at the center or the 'floor' but appears at the left side instead. This is my code and a screenshot of what's happening.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 500
FPS = 60
TITLE = 'FOOD DROP'
SIZE = 190

# Colors

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE_SKY = (152, 166, 255)

# Display

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

# Surfaces

floor_surface = pygame.Surface((WIDTH, 100))
floor_surface.fill(BLUE_SKY)
floor_rect = floor_surface.get_rect(midbottom=(200, 500))

# Images

LOAD_DITTO = pygame.image.load('Graphics/ditto.png')
DITTO = pygame.transform.scale(LOAD_DITTO, (SIZE, SIZE))

# Time

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()


class Figure:

    def draw_figure(self, mouse_x):
        SCREEN.blit(DITTO, (mouse_x - 90, 330))


# Game loop

SCREEN_UPDATE = pygame.USEREVENT
# main_game = Main()
figure = Figure()

running = True
while running:
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    SCREEN.fill(WHITE)
    SCREEN.blit(floor_surface, floor_rect)
    figure.draw_figure(mx)
    pygame.display.update()
```

When i run the program, this happens:

[image]

And i want the image to appear right at the center or the x-axis, not the border, i don't know why is this happening. Just to state, that screenshot was taken when the mouse hadn't been placed over the display.

Answer (score 1):

If the mouse pointer is not in the window (out of focus), the initial position of the mouse pointer is (0, 0). Therefore [`pygame.mouse.get_pos`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) returns (0, 0). It is also not possible to set the mouse position with [`pygame.mouse.set_pos`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_pos) if it is not in the window.
Initialize the variables `mx` and `mx` with the center of the window. Change the mouse position only when the mouse pointer is in the window (in focus). [`pygame.mouse.get_focused`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_focused) can be used to test whether the mouse is in the window.

```py
mx, my = SCREEN.get_rect().center

running = True
while running:
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if pygame.mouse.get_focused():
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    SCREEN.fill(WHITE)
    SCREEN.blit(floor_surface, floor_rect)
    figure.draw_figure(mx)
    pygame.display.update() 

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```